# Tuples not showing proper data in PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to load below data in PIG.
    (3,8,9) (4,5,6)
    (1,4,7) (3,7,5)
    (2,5,8) (9,5,8)

```
A = LOAD 'data' AS (t1:tuple(t1a:int, t1b:int,t1c:int),t2:tuple(t2a:int,t2b:int,t2c:int));
```

While dumping, getting only first tuple , why the other tuple not showing up. Please help.

```
dump A;

((3,8,9),)
((1,4,7),)
((2,5,8),)
```

Comment: (3,8,9)(4,5,6)
(1,4,7)(3,7,5)
(2,5,8)(9,5,8)

Comment: did my answer of `USING PigStorage(',');` help?

Answer (score 0):

`LOAD` in Pig expects tab separated data by default. Reference: http://pig.apache.org/docs/latest/func.html#pigstorage. Its possible that your input data has space separated tuples and hence the second tuple goes missing in each line.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `A = LOAD 'data' AS (t1:tuple(t1a:int, t1b:int,t1c:int),t2:tuple(t2a:int,t2b:int,t2c:int)) USING PigStorage(',');`